# How to send message to all participants of multi user chat room using smack

Tags: xmpp, smack, multiuserchat

I am creating multi user chat room for group chat where multi user can have chat. I am using **smack** for this within **jsp** . I have added message listener for multi user chat room after joining the room.

```
// Get the MultiUserChatManager
        MultiUserChatManager manager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(xmppConnection);

        // Create a MultiUserChat using an CustomXMPPConnection for a room
        MultiUserChat multiUserChat = manager.getMultiUserChat(chatRoomName + "@conference." + xmppConnection.getServiceName());

        multiUserChat.addMessageListener(new MessageListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void processMessage(Message message) {
                System.out.println("Message listener Received message in send message: "
                        + (message != null ? message.getBody() : "NULL") + "  , Message sender :" + message.getFrom());
            }
        });
```

Code for sending message :

```
Message message = new Message(chatRoomName, Message.Type.groupchat);
message.setBody(msg);
message.setType(Message.Type.groupchat);
message.setTo(chatRoomName);
multiUserChat.sendMessage(message);
```

My question is after receiving message in Message Listener how will i show message to other users?

Comment: Your question made a 180° turn. First it was "how can I send a message to all participants of a multi user chat?" (this is was the title still says), now it's "how can I display a message once I received it in a message listener?". That obviously depends on whatever you use to interact with the user, in your case likely JSP. So maybe some kind of browser notification and/or however you visualize the chat?

Comment: @Flow i am sorry for not clearing my question firstly. i am working forwardly for solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `MultiUserChat.sendMessage()`.

Comment: Yes i have send the message and listener is also responding to that. My question is how will i show that message to another users?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the question.

Comment: @Jennifer you have to trust more who reply you ;) Simply any client will be automatically notificated by his own listener. To be notified a client must join the room and stay in the room abd add a listener, so it's all automatized

Comment: @MrPk Yes i do trust who reply me. It was just that i was away for sometime. So I could not reply. I will try to implement the answer.